# 'Error: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined' when loading react-native application

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Usually I'll refresh a few times and the app will start working again, but it's been going on and off for the past few hours, with 90% of the time, me getting this error.

Do you have a suggestion about how to approach this mind-numbing problem?

This tends to happen after I install a new library with npm install. in this case it was react-native-sqlite. Sometimes `npm update` fixes it, though not this time

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by:

1. deleting everything in my XCode 'Derived Data' folder
2. `rm -rf` my node_modules
3. Reset settings in iOS Simulator